# How to avoid branching for a call where the number of arguments is dependent on conditionals?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, boost-process

I'm converting some code from using `CreateProcess` to use [boost-process](/questions/tagged/boost-process) instead. I need to replace my `CreateProcess` usages with `boost::process::child`. The problem is they have incompatible ways for me to say "I want to use the default value". What used to be a one line command has become sixteen `if` statements.

The function I currently use works like this (simplified):

```
void CreateProcess(int, float);
```

Each parameter had a value you could use to indicate you wanted the default. I'll use 0 in this example:

```
int int_param = ...;
float float_param = ...;

CreateProcess(0, 0); //Use both defaults
CreateProcess(int_param, 0); //Use default float
CreateProcess(0, float_param); //Use default int
CreateProcess(int_param, float_param); //No defaults
```

This is a common design. You know what I am talking about. Whether I wanted to use the default value or not could be decided with a simple conditional, such as `(... ? 0 : int_param)`. This allowed every `CreateProcess` call to be a single line of code.

```
CreateProcess( (... ? 0 : int_param), (... ? 0 : float_param) );
```

Where I used to call `CreateProcess`, I now want to create a `child` class. The constructor for `child` works like this:

```
template<typename ...Args>
explicit child(Args&&...args);
```

Instead of passing a specific value to use a default, I have to *pass nothing*.

```
int int_param = ...;
float float_param = ...;

child c; //Use both defaults
child c(int_param); //Use default float
child c(float_param); //Use default int
child c(int_param, float_param); //No defaults
child c(float_param, int_param); //Argument order is irrelevant
```

So far my only "solution" is to use `if` branches.

```
if (...) {
    if (...)
        child c;
    else
        child c(float_param);
} else {
    if (...)
        child c(int_param);
    else
        child c(int_param, float_param);
}
```

This example has only two possible arguments and it becomes four branches. **The real `child` has four possible arguments, so every instance has sixteen branches.**

What I would like is some way of building the call to avoid this branching. A solution specific to `boost::process` is also fine.

FYI, the last two arguments to `child` may or may not be the same type.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Are you asking how to rework your design to avoid branching? What does it have to do with variadic templates? (not varargs)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The issue is that with first branch this seems ok, then I also to differentiate with commands (either cmd, or exe and cmd is given). Then Im at 4 different branches/type of calls. In the future, i plan to do something with the environment as well (this might not yield another branch but if it did then i would have ~8) - I hope you can see this is a lot of boilerplate branching.

Comment: Right but what does that have to do with Boost or variadic templates?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if theres a solution that works for `boost::process` in this case then that might be fine. A generel solution would also work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think OP's problem is that the old function would accept values like `nullptr` to mean _"use the default"_, but the new function requires you to either supply a valid value or not enter the argument at all to use the default. So now they are forced to convert single-line function calls to massive spanning `if-then` trees based on how many parameters they need to supply.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tried to clarify the post now

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish thank you, that is spot on !

Comment: Why "too broad" ? I would like to know so I can narrow it down

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish Good explanation. We could do with that in the question.

Comment: Okay, here's a follow-up question: why variadic templates?

Comment: Your "before" example still works and doesn't need default arguments

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The constructor is a variadic template function. I don't mind removing the tag though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The old one works, yes, but I am trying to convert to `boost::process` (reason: i wan't to use the pipe api provided with `boost::process`)

Comment: I don't see how you can get around the need for branching when `boost::process` requires you to use different ctors. How do you envision a solution looking?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thats a good point. Maybe some expression template that allows binding one argument at a time could be an option - but Im not sure.

Comment: Is every possible argument to `child` a different type, or does it have multiple arguments that can be the same type?

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish The last, arguments can have same (or different) type

Comment: Maybe write the variadic function to accept `std::optional<T>` arguments, ignoring them when empty and treating them the same as `T` arguments when not empty?

Comment: (I take it "avoid branching" here means "don't need to write tons of `if` and `else` at the call site", not "avoid branching instructions at the assembly/CPU level".)

Comment: @aschepler thats true,and a good idea, thing is, I cannot change the target function

Comment: Ah, I see you've rewritten the question. This is much better now 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to leave out parameters in the call, and do things like:

```
create_child();
create_child(std::make_optional(int_param));
create_child(std::make_optional(float_param),
             (... ? std::optional<int>{} : int_param);
```

You can use some templates and a recursive function. The following code is an example. There are ways to make this better, like only creating one `child` and not returning a bunch, or using perfect forwarding.

```
//Recursion base case
//Recieves values to pass to child in a tuple
//Returns created child
template <typename... Ts>
child create_child_detail(std::tuple<Ts...> t)
{
    //Is there a better way to apply a tuple to a ctor?
    return std::apply([](Ts... ts){ return child(ts...); }, t);
}

//Recursive function
//Removes arguments from variadic template and adds arguments to tuple
template <typename... Ts, typename O, typename... Os>
child create_child_detail(std::tuple<Ts...> t, std::optional<O> o, std::optional<Os>... os)
{
    if (o) //Valid optional, add value to tuple to send to child
        return create_child_detail(std::tuple_cat(t, std::make_tuple(*o)), os...);
    else //Invalid optional, value should not be added to child
        return create_child_detail(t, os...);
}

//Called by user
//Just calls create_child_detail
template <typename... Ts>
child create_child(std::optional<Ts>... ts)
{
    return create_child_detail(std::tuple<>{}, ts...);
}
```

Empty optionals are removed. The arguments are passed to `child` in the order you wrote them. It can take any number of arguments. I tested it out [on Coliru here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb1811f8ffab2163) so you can play with it.

Comment: std::make_from_tuple springs to mind. (and btw. a big thank you, that saved my day)

Answer (score 1):

Use a function to create `child` objects which contains the branches. Pass `std::optional` as parameters:

```
child make_child(const std::optional<int>& int_param,
                 const std::optional<float>& float_param)
{
    if (int_param && float_param) {
        return child(std::to_string(int_param.value()),
                     std::to_string(float_param.value()));
    }

    // Rest of the branches ...
}
```

This allows you to create a `child` object like this:

```
child c = make_child(... ? std::optional<int>() : int_param,
                     ... ? std::optional<float>() : float_param);
```

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish Fixed. It's quite unfortunate.